# Adding a new worker to a list but keep it sorted by name

Tags: c, list

I have to add a new worker to the workers list, but I have to put it in the right place, by alphabetically order.

I put up few options for the new name :

1. the list is empty so I just put the new name in the list
2. the list has 1 worker in it
3. the new name < the existing name
4. new name is bigger then the one before it, but smaller then the next
5. the new name bigger than the last name

Where did I go wrong ?

```
//first function-add a new worker to the list//
Worker * addWorker(Worker *head, char name[], char *city, int id, float 
salary)
{
Worker *new = (Worker *)malloc(sizeof(Worker));
strcpy(new->name, name);
new->city = city;
new->id = id;
new->salary = salary;
if (head == NULL)  //checks if the list is empty//
{
    new->next = NULL;
    head = new;
    return head;
}
if (length(head) == 1) //checks if the list has 1 person only //
{
    if (head->name < new->name)
    {
        head->next = new;
        new->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    if (head->name > new->name)
    {
        new->next = head;
        return new;
    }
}
Worker *x = head;
Worker *y = head->next;
while (x != NULL)
{
    if (x->name > new->name) //checks if the name needs to be first in 
the list//
    {
        new->next = x;
        return new;
    }
    if ((x->name < new->name) && (y->name > new->name)) // checks if the 
name needs to be somewhere in the middle of the list//
    {
        x->next = new;
        new->next = y;
        return head;
    }

    if ((x->name < new->name) && (y==NULL)) //checks if the name needs to 
be last in the list//
    {
        x->next = new;
        new->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    x = x->next;
    y = y->next;
}

return head;

}
```

Comment: You cannot compare strings with `<`. Google for `strcmp`. Also, what is your question?

Comment: thanks for the comment
you mean like that - if (strcmp(x->name,new->name)>0) //checks if the name needs to be first in the list ?

Comment: if *that* then `x->name` comes *later* in alphabetical ordering than `new->name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but your code is so complicated I preferred to not try to understand it

If *addWorker* returns the new worker (rather than the new head of the list) the first parameter must be the location where the head is memorized, so a `Worker ** head`. After you just have to iterate on the list up to the right position to insert the new worker.

To compare strings use *strcmp*

A solution is :

```
//first function-add a new worker to the list//
Worker * addWorker(Worker ** head, char name[], char *city, int id, float salary)
{
  Worker * new = malloc(sizeof(Worker));

  strcpy(new->name, name); /* hope the name is not too long to be saved in Worker */
  new->city = city; /* hope the city is always a valid string */
  new->id = id;
  new->salary = salary;

  while ((*head) && (strcmp(name, (*head)->name) > 0))
    head = &(*head)->next;

  new->next = *head;
  *head = new;

  return new;
}
```

Note it is strange to not have the same behavior for the city and for the name, but I respected that.

---

If I had the some definitions to have a full program including printing and deletion :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Worker {
  char name[10];
  const char * city;
  int id;
  float salary;
  struct Worker * next;
} Worker;

//first function-add a new worker to the list//
Worker * addWorker(Worker ** head, char name[], char *city, int id, float salary)
{
  Worker * new = (Worker *)malloc(sizeof(Worker));

  strcpy(new->name, name); /* hope the name is not too long to be saved in Worker */
  new->city =  city; /* hope the city is always a valid string */
  new->id = id;
  new->salary = salary;

  while ((*head) && (strcmp(name, (*head)->name) > 0))
    head = &(*head)->next;

  new->next = *head;
  *head = new;

  return new;
}

void pr(Worker * l)
{
  while (l != NULL) {
    printf("%s %s %d %f\n", l->name, l->city, l->id, l->salary);
    l = l->next;
  }
}

void del(Worker * l)
{

  while (l != NULL) {
    Worker * w = l;

    l = l->next;
    free(w);
  }
}

int main()
{
  Worker * l = NULL;

  addWorker(&l, "aze", "c1", 1, 1);
  addWorker(&l, "qsd", "c2", 2, 2);
  addWorker(&l, "aaa", "c3", 3, 3);
  addWorker(&l, "wxc", "c4", 4, 4);

  pr(l);

  del(l);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall w.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
aaa c3 3 3.000000
aze c1 1 1.000000
qsd c2 2 2.000000
wxc c4 4 4.000000
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==17053== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17053== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17053== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17053== Command: ./a.out
==17053== 
aaa c3 3 3.000000
aze c1 1 1.000000
qsd c2 2 2.000000
wxc c4 4 4.000000
==17053== 
==17053== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17053==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17053==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 1,136 bytes allocated
==17053== 
==17053== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17053== 
==17053== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17053== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

---

Second proposal in case *addWorker* returns the new head of the list rather than the new worker, new definition for *addWorker* and *main*

```
Worker * addWorker(Worker * head, char name[], char *city, int id, float salary)
{
  Worker ** phead = &head;
  Worker * new = (Worker *)malloc(sizeof(Worker));

  strcpy(new->name, name); /* hope the name is not too long to be saved in Worker */
  new->city =  city; /* hope the city is always a valid string */
  new->id = id;
  new->salary = salary;

  while ((*phead) && (strcmp(name, (*phead)->name) > 0))
    phead = &(*phead)->next;

  new->next = *phead;
  *phead = new;

  return (new->next == head) ? new : head;
}

int main()
{
  Worker * l = NULL;

  l = addWorker(l, "aze", "c1", 1, 1);
  l = addWorker(l, "qsd", "c2", 2, 2);
  l = addWorker(l, "aaa", "c3", 3, 3);
  l = addWorker(l, "wxc", "c4", 4, 4);

  pr(l);

  del(l);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the long complicated code, really got lost with this task
unfortunatly i have to use the function signature given above, so i cant reallly use your code. any other tips ?

Comment: @Gimi is the signature must be respected that means the return value is the new list, ok I edit my answer ...

Comment: it has to be exactly like this :
Worker * addWorker(Worker *head, char name[],char *city,
int id, float salary) 

note that it is Worker *head and not Worker **head like in your code

Comment: @Gimi yes, I did, look at the new version